# ERROR: Function name must be astring - return $next($request);

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I´m getting the error **Function name must be a string** and it points to the statement `return $next($request);`.

I just updated my Laravel version to 5.8 and backpack to 3.6, IDK if this has something to be with the error.

Attached is an image of the error.

[image]

Comment: It might be the middleware in the stack before this one, and its not passing on the $next correctly?

Comment: It's not passing :(